# How to start apache while it shows fail to stop apache

Tags: phpmyadmin

**Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.**
The status of the lampp is ok but the localhost is not opening,while stopping,it fails and the above error is shown.how to solve this problem?
what are the commands for that
?

Comment: Are you sure it is lamp and not xamp? The start/stop script of xamp has a "> /dev/null 2>&1" in it (why is beyond me) that prevents you from seeing the correct error message. Our native lamp does not have this kind of feature. Remove it from the script, stop apache and fix the message it shows :)

Comment: i am using ubuntu,and the problem is above mentioned,localhost is not opening.while seeing the status through $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status ->it shows all is running but while stopping them it shows fail to stop apache.what is the sollution?

Comment: Please post the part of the script after `stop)`.

Comment: Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-3...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
fail.
kill returned 1.

Comment: OK, so it *is* XAMPP. As @Rinzwind suggests, delete the `>/dev/null 2>&1` part from the start/stop script, try to stop the service again, and post the output above.

Comment: @user3514447 please follow up on the comments from me and jos

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue. Since you are getting an error stopping Apache and ProFTP only, you need to delete these two files:

`/opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid`

and

`/opt/lampp/var/proftpd.pid`

When you delete the httpd.pid, Apache is automatically killed. And similar happens when you remove the proftpd.pid.

So now you can go ahead and restart the server and new fresh files will be created. :)

Comment: I followed it. But still it is not solving my issue in Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What error are you getting? I tried the solution on 14.04 only.

Comment: Showing "The webpage is not available" when I tried this url. `localhost/phpmyadmin`. I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: This is not an issue with Apache (or the one being discussed in this page). If you are able to open http://localhost/ and you see something there, it means that apache is running fine.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the following files:

- `$XAMPP_ROOT/logs/httpd.pid`
- `$XAMPP_ROOT/var/mysql/$(hostname).pid`
- `$XAMPP_ROOT/var/proftpd.pid`

Comment: How does this solve anything? What does it do?

Comment: If this files exists XAMPP thinks that Apache,MySQL and ProFTPD already running. Its can happens if you hard reboot your PC when XAMPP is running.

Comment: Look how i solved this issue - http://joxi.ru/v29dGnQILqXRmG

Answer (score 0):

When you see **`Stopping Apache...fail. apachectl returned 1`** while starting **lampp** then Run Following command:

```
 sudo rm -f /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid
```

After running above command **restart lampp**, it will work definitely.